# digital IQ modulators

Tags: signal-analysis

when it comes to digital I/Q signal power measurement we know that this power is viewed as $I^2+Q^2$ (as its polar form). This is the power as referred to final analogue signal. Yet the IQ modulator does not convert I/Q to polar form, instead only the final I is output to real world say in the RF modulator.
When I model two I/Q mixers it does not show that final power is $I^2 + Q^2$ but rather just $I^2$:

```
x = randn(1,1024)+j*randn(1,1024); %random I/Q input
sincos1 = exp(j*2*pi*(0:1023)*.01); 
y1 = x.*sincos1; % first digital IQ modulator 

sincos2 = exp(j*2*pi*(0:1023)*.1);
y2 = real(y1.*sincos2); %rf IQ mixer giving final analogue output
```

if you check power of y2 you will see it is close to real(y1) rather than complex y1.
I ask this because for all power dependent applications e.g. DPD we assume power is $I^2+Q^2$
what am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power of the final real-valued signal $y_2$ is half the power of $y_1$ because you take the real part (and thus reduce power by a factor 2). The real part of $y_1$ is already the sum of the I-component and the Q-component, not only the I-component:

$$Re\{y_1\}=Re\{x\}\cos\omega_1 t - Im\{x\}\sin\omega_1 t= I-Q$$

So the original formula $I^2+Q^2$ is correct, you just need to apply a factor of $1/2$ if you don't compensate for taking the real-part. This is why in some textbooks the real part operation in a bandpass modulator is 'implemented' as $\sqrt{2}Re\{\cdot\}$; this will keep the power unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Matt,However I am implying that already as in my matlab code which shows power of real(y2) is half of complex y1. So let me rephrase the question with perspective of DPD case as example. In DPD design we take lot of effort to get sqrt of I^2+Q^2 in order to address lookup tables for dpd terms. If we simply say that output power at PA just needs scaling then why designers stress on sqrt(I^2+Q^2) rather than just get I to address the terms?

Comment: I think the problem is that you think that $Re\{y_1\}$ is the I-component. However, $Re\{y_1\}$ is already the sum of both components, because $Re\{y_1\}=x_R\cos\omega_1t-x_I\sin\omega_1t$.

Comment: I edited my answer to add more clarity, hopefully.

Comment: many thanks, that clears it. I was sort of thinking that we are viewing a polar version of I/Q at PA but it is only the I signal containing components of both original I & Q